# Можно ли уйти от сканирования индекса в большой таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server, index

Вычитал, что существует тип индекса ColumnStore.

Ранее с ним не работал и не знаю, что за зверь такой.

На официальном сайте написано, что данный индекс способен повысить производительность при аналитических запросах, когда выполняется работа с большими объемами данных, чего я как раз и хочу достичь.

Сценарий: есть 2 здоровенных таблицы, которые нужно между собой соединить и допустим, посчитать кол-во денег за определенный период.

Собственно, вопросы:

1. на какие поля рационально повесить данный тип индекса?
2. Если вешать его на поля по которым происходит JOIN, то нужно его на обе таблицы вешать или можно смешивать?
3. Если его повесить поле по которому выполняется сумма, то это сыграет какую-нибудь роль?
4. Где-то читал, что таблицы с этим типом индекса становятся необновляемыми. Правда ли это?

Определения таблиц:

```
Таблица 1: ID PK INT,Date DateTime бла бла бла

Таблица 2: ID PK INT, Money FLOAT, бла бла бла
```

Соединяются эти таблицы по ID.

Сейчас при соединении этих таблиц выполняется сканирование индекса, что занимает много времени. Если на дату повесить индекс, то не особо шустрее становится.

P.S Это абстрактный запрос и таблицы. По факту там чуть больше соединений и агрегации данных.

И вот я думаю, как бы это все дело сделать шустрее. Могу конечно с Force Seek поиграться, но не с проста же планировщик выбирает сканирование?

Comment: Почитал разные источники... да, таблица становится readonly. т.е. на рабочих таблицах их использовать нельзя. Кроме того для join с другой таблицей он абсолютно не подходит, потому что по такому индексу невозможно точечно искать конкретное значение, только полным сканированием индекса. В общем могут себя показать только если у вас в запросе используется только несколько столбцов и предполагается полное использование таблицы, а не нескольких отдельных строк

Comment: т.е. деньги за большой период считайте, но объединять при этом с дуругой таблицей не надо (разве что уже после группировки и подсчета)

Comment: _"есть 2 здоровенных таблицы, которые нужно между собой соединить и допустим, посчитать кол-во денег за определенный период"_ определение таблиц и типовой запрос (хотя бы приблизительные) лишними не были бы

Comment: @i-one, добавил чуть больше конкретики.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] тип индекса ColumnStore [...] что за зверь такой.

Вспомним, сначала, что такое обычный некластерный индекс. Что для него характерно? У такого индекса есть ключ и указатель на данные (*RID* либо *clustered index key*), который неявно включен в индекс:

```
INDEX ([KeyColumn1], [KeyColumn2], ...)
    INDEX ([KeyColumn1], [KeyColumn2], ...) INCLUDE (RID)
    INDEX ([KeyColumn1], [KeyColumn2], ...) INCLUDE ([CI_KeyColumn1], [CI_KeyColumn2], ...)
```

Для оптимизации *Index Scan* и *Index Seek* операций в некластерные индексы также могут включаться дополнительные столбцы:

```
INDEX ([KeyColumn1], [KeyColumn2], ...) INCLUDE ([SomeColumn1], [SomeColumn2], ...)
```

Так вот, семантически, *columnstore* - вырожденный случай индекса, у которого нет ключевых столбцов, и все столбцы индекса являются включенными (*included*):

```
INDEX () INCLUDE ([SomeColumn1], [SomeColumn2], ...)
```

И если *nonclustered columnstore* худо-бедно ещё как-то можно назвать индексом, поскольку он включает хотя бы указатель на данные (неявно, как и обычный некластерный индекс), то *clustered columnstore* назвать индексом можно лишь с очень большой натяжкой, т.к. у него нет ни ключа, ни указателя, по сути он - просто хранилище (подобно *heap*).

Меняем теперь слово `INCLUDE` на `COLUMNSTORE` (в действительности это, конечно же, не простая замена, за новым словом кроется также и особая организация индекса), адаптируем синтаксис, и вот он

```
COLUMNSTORE INDEX ([SomeColumn1], [SomeColumn2], ...)
```

предназначенный для оптимизации операций сканирования.

---

*Columnstore* индекс (не считая его *delta-store* части) хранит данные следующим образом. Предположим есть таблица `TABLE (A, B, C)` со строками

```
R1 (A1, B1, C1),
R2 (A2, B2, C2),
R3 (A3, B3, C3),
...
```

Исходные данные разбиваются на группы строк (*rowgroup*). В каждую группу объединяется до 1048576 (2<sup>20</sup>) строк. Если построение индекса происходит в условиях memory-pressure, то это число может быть меньше. Все значения одного столбца группы хранятся вместе и формируют сегмент (*segment*).

```
RowGroup1 (
    A_Segment1 (A1, A2, ... A_n)
    B_Segment1 (B1, B2, ... B_n)
    C_Segment1 (C1, C2, ... C_n)
)
RowGroup2 (
    A_Segment2 (A_n+1, A_n+2, ... A_n+k)
    B_Segment2 (B_n+1, B_n+2, ... B_n+k)
    C_Segment2 (C_n+1, C_n+2, ... C_n+k)
)
...
```

Данные групп и сегментов *columnstore* индекса могут читаться независимо. Например, для запроса

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A)
FROM T;
```

будут прочитаны только *A_Segment1, A_Segment2,* и т.д., данные лишних для запроса столбцов затронуты не будут.

В случае обычных *rowstore* таблиц (и индексов), если столбец нужен для запроса, то страницы данных, содержащие строки таблицы, зачитываются в кэш полностью (с данными всех столбцов). Столбец может быть прочитан относительно независимо, только если данные уже находятся в кэше.

Впрочем, даже в случаях, когда в таблице нет "лишних" столбцов, в *rowstore* таблицах и индексах издержки на хранение данных могут быть достаточно высокими (что сказывается затем и при чтении). Особенно это касается таблиц, состоящих из небольшого числа столбцов простых типов. Типичный пример - таблицы, связывающие две сущности (пара *int* столбцов), в них сами данные занимают лишь примерно половину объёма хранения, другая же половина - это, в основном, заголовки строк. В *columnstore* издержки всевозможных заголовков в пересчёте на строку данных существенно меньше.

В заголовках сегментов *columnstore* индекса хрянятся минимальные и максимальные значения по столбцу для данного сегмента, благодаря чему, при наличии предикатов

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A)
FROM T
WHERE A BETWEEN @a1 AND @a2;
```

в некоторых случаях может выполняться частичное сканирование, при котором часть групп или сегментов просто пропускается (т.н. *rowgroup elimination* или *segment elimination*).

К тому же, данные в сегментах хранятся в сжатом виде. За счёт того, что в столбце данные одного типа, достигается хорошая сжимаемость. Так, например, столбец в 10 млн. значений *int*, в котором всего лишь с десяток разнообразных значений (какой-нибудь FK-столбец, например) может занимать в *columnstore* всего несколько килобайт. Неповторяющиеся данные тоже могут неплохо сжиматься. Например, столбец *identity* в 10 млн. значений *int* занимает в *columnstore* пару десятков мегабайт, вместо положенных ~38 Мб чистых данных.

Всё это значительно снижает стоимость сканирования *columnstore* индекса по сравнению со стоимостью сканирования *rowstore* таблиц и индексов.

Оптимизированное хранение - не единственная вещь, прибавляющая производительности *columnstore* индексам. При обработке данных, поступающих из *columnstore* индекса, вдобавок, используется пакетный режим обработки (*batch mode processing*), при котором строки обрабатываются операторами плана запроса не по одной, а пакетами, что снижает издержки (и, соответственно, затраты CPU). За счёт этого могут более быстро происходить, например, соединения и агрегации. Список операторов, поддерживающих *batch mode*, с каждой новой версией SqlServer расширяется. Также *batch mode* по-видимому [станет когда-нибудь](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/938021) поддерживаться и для *rowstore* индексов. Пока же, чтобы задействовать *batch mode* для *rowstore*, прибегают к определённым [ухищрениям](https://sqlworkbooks.com/2017/05/batch-mode-hacks-for-rowstore-queries-in-sql-server/).

В последних версиях SqlServer *columnstore*-индексы (в т.ч. и *nonclustered*) могут обновляться и не блокируют обновление данных в таблице, однако, устройство *columnstore*-индексов таково, что они более производительно работают, когда данные в них только добавляются, но не удаляются и не изменяются. Поэтому они больше подходят для использования в OLAP-сценариях.

---

> Сценарий: есть 2 здоровенных таблицы, которые нужно между собой
>   соединить и допустим, посчитать кол-во денег за определенный период.
>   [...] Определения таблиц [...] Соединяются эти таблицы по ID.

Смоделируем ситуацию. Итак, наши таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    [ID] int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date] datetime NOT NULL,
    [BlaBlaBla] binary(200) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    [ID] int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_T2 PRIMARY KEY,
    [Money] float NOT NULL,
    [BlaBlaBla] binary(200) NULL
);

ALTER TABLE T2
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) REFERENCES T1 ([ID]);
```

тестовые данные (10 млн. строк в каждой таблице)

```
WITH tally AS (
    SELECT N = row_number() over (order by @@spid)
    FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b
)
INSERT INTO T1 WITH (TABLOCK) ([ID], [Date], [BlaBlaBla])
SELECT TOP (10000000)
    N, dateadd(minute, N, '2010-01-01'), 0x00
FROM tally;

WITH tally AS (
    SELECT N = row_number() over (order by @@spid)
    FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b
)
INSERT INTO T2 WITH (TABLOCK) ([ID], [Money], [BlaBlaBla])
SELECT TOP (10000000)
    N, rand(checksum(newid())), 0x00
FROM tally;
```

Наш типовой запрос будет

```
DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime;
SET @start = ...;
SET @end = ...;

SELECT sum(T2.[Money])
FROM T1
    JOIN T2 ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
WHERE T1.[Date] >= @start AND T1.[Date] < @end;
```

Для такого запроса я возьму обычные индексы

```
CREATE INDEX IX_T1_Date ON T1 ([Date]) INCLUDE ([ID]);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_T2 ON T2 ([ID]) INCLUDE ([Money]);
```

и *columnstore* индексы

```
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX CX_T1 ON T1 ([ID], [Date]);
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX CX_T2 ON T2 ([ID], [Money]);
```

Столбцы `[ID]` в индексы `IX_T1_Date`, `CX_T1` и `CX_T2` включать, в принципе, не обязательно, т.к. `PK_T1` и `PK_T2` - кластерные.

На `T1`, однако, я построю индексы в таком порядке

```
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX CX_T1 ON T1 ([Date]) WITH (MAXDOP = 1);
CREATE INDEX IX_T1_Date ON T1 ([Date]);
```

чтобы данные для `CX_T1` брались не из `IX_T1_Date`, а из `PK_T1` (при его сканировании будет использоваться *ordered index scan*). В этом случае сегменты `[Data]` столбца в `CX_T1` заполнятся датами по возрастанию (т.к. в исходных данных даты возрастают с увеличением `[ID]`), и *segment elimination* может быть задействован эффективнее.

Сначала оценим худший случай - посчитаем полную сумму, указав заведомо больший интервал дат

```
DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime;
SET @start = '2000-01-01';
SET @end = '2050-01-01';
```

Использование того или иного вида индексов фиксируем *hint*-ами. Включим вывод статистики:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
```

Сумма с использованием обычных индексов:

```
SELECT sum(T2.[Money])
FROM T1 WITH (INDEX(IX_T1_Date))
    JOIN T2 WITH (INDEX(IX_T2)) ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
WHERE T1.[Date] >= @start AND T1.[Date] < @end;
```

Затраты:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22310, ...
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22332, ...

CPU time = 6469 ms, elapsed time = 6516 ms.
```

С использованием *columnstore* индексов:

```
SELECT sum(T2.[Money])
FROM T1 WITH (INDEX(CX_T1))
    JOIN T2 WITH (INDEX(CX_T2)) ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
WHERE T1.[Date] >= '2000-01-01' AND T1.[Date] < '2050-01-01';
```

Затраты:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 26732, ...
Table 'T2'. Segment reads 10, segment skipped 0.
Table 'T1'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 26732, ...
Table 'T1'. Segment reads 10, segment skipped 0.

CPU time = 875 ms, elapsed time = 869 ms.
```

Далее, сумма за 5 лет:

```
SET @start = '2015-01-01 00:00';
SET @end = '2020-01-01 00:00';
```

затраты с обычными индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22310, ...
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5875, ...

CPU time = 2672 ms, elapsed time = 2673 ms.
```

затраты с *columnstore* индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 11208, ...
Table 'T2'. Segment reads 4, segment skipped 6.
Table 'T1'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 11208, ...
Table 'T1'. Segment reads 4, segment skipped 6.

CPU time = 282 ms,  elapsed time = 282 ms.
```

(*segment skipped* в выводе - признак применения *segment elimination* оптимизации).

Сумма за один год:

```
SET @start = '2017-01-01 00:00';
SET @end = '2018-01-01 00:00';
```

затраты с обычными индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22310, ...
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1178, ...

CPU time = 1344 ms, elapsed time = 1351 ms.
```

затраты с *columnstore* индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 5604, ...
Table 'T2'. Segment reads 2, segment skipped 8.
Table 'T1'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 5604, ...
Table 'T1'. Segment reads 2, segment skipped 8.

CPU time = 63 ms, elapsed time = 64 ms.
```

Сумма за один месяц:

```
SET @start = '2017-01-01 00:00';
SET @end = '2017-02-01 00:00';
```

затраты с обычными индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22310, ...
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 104, ...

CPU time = 1125 ms, elapsed time = 1122 ms.
```

затраты с *columnstore* индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 2802, ...
Table 'T2'. Segment reads 1, segment skipped 9.
Table 'T1'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 2802, ...
Table 'T1'. Segment reads 1, segment skipped 9.

CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 10 ms.
```

Во всех случаях выше, *columnstore* индекс показал заметно лучшую производительность.

Однако при запросе суммы на конкретную дату обычные индексы давали выигрыш

```
DECLARE @date datetime;
SET @date = '2017-08-01 12:45';

SELECT sum(T2.[Money])
FROM T1
    JOIN T2
WHERE T1.Date = @date;
```

затраты с обычными индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, ...
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, ...

CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

затраты с *columnstore* индексами:

```
Table 'T2'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 2802, ...
Table 'T2'. Segment reads 1, segment skipped 9.
Table 'T1'. Scan count 2, ..., lob logical reads 2802, ...
Table 'T1'. Segment reads 1, segment skipped 9.

CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 5 ms.
```

Также при запросе суммы за небольшой период (на этих данных - несколько часов и менее) обычные индексы показывали лучшую производительность, чем *columnstore*. Впрочем, из-за неважной статистики по дате, для этого мне иногда приходилось прибегать к использованию `FORCESEEK` подсказки на `T2`.

Answer (score 3):

Columnstore индекс - это индекс, в котором изменен механизм хранения данных. Если грубо, то классические индексы хранят данные построчно, т.е. идет первое значение первой строки, второе значение первой строки, ..., последнее значение первой строки, потом вторая строка и т.д. Колоночный индекс хранит данные поколоночно - первое значение первой строки, первое значение второй строки и т.д.

За счет такого хранения достигается возможность лучшего сжатия данных, если данные в колонке часто повторяются, лучшая скорость скана таблицы по нескольким полям - если в обычном индексе вы вычитываете все поля индекса, то в колоночном - только нужные поля.

Теперь ответы:

1. На все поля, которые участвуют в запросах, требующих полного скана таблицы.
2. Смешивать можно, тип индекса влияет на способ вычитки данных, но не на тип соединения.
3. Повлияет только на скорость чтения данных, не на скорость агрегации.
4. Это актуально для всех колоночных индексов в SQL Server 2012 и некластерных колоночных индексов для SQL Server 2014 - они, действительно, необновляемые. В SQL Server 2016 было сделано множество улучшений, в т.ч. возможность обновления таких индексов.

Подробно о возможностях работы с колоночными индексами в разных версиях SQL Server можно посмотреть здесь:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-what-s-new

И последний ответ: SQL Server действительно может выбрать Scan вместо Seek в случае, если считает, что он - дешевле. Такое может быть, если Seek'ов надо делать слишком много, и проще один раз вычитать всю таблицу. Именно для такого случая колоночный индекс может помочь.

Comment: Те не имеет смысл его вешать на первичный ключ большой таблицы, раз вы говорите, что он шустрее работает с повторяющимися данными?

Comment: @iluxa1810, про первичный ключ не скажу - надо смотреть и проверять. Думаю, первичный ключ тоже желательно включить, чтобы все данные вычитывались из одного индекса (а первичный ключ вам, я так понял, нужен - вы по нему соединение делаете), но не могу сказать этого точно - сам не проверял.